# Hide and show elements using checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Good Day! Want to hide/show elements using checkboxes attribute ("checked", false/true). So I created this example to explain what I want to have.
https://jsfiddle.net/9LzLm9hx/4/
 Try to check and uncheck category checkbox and then push the button `hide/show`. When this checkbox is `false` it hides, but I can't make them `true` after that. Thanks.

Comment: check the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9LzLm9hx/6/)

Comment: not working same as previuos one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same `id` and `class` name in your elements and you can sum it up to the following:

```js
$('.js-ok').on('click', function() {
  //iterate through checkboxes
  $(".custom-checkbox :checkbox").each(function() {
    //toggle specific element according to the checkbox status
    $("." + $(this).attr("id")).toggle($(this).prop("checked"));
  })
});
```

```css
#common {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#common + label + span {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: red;
}
.col-xs-3 {
  margin-top: 29px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.category {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal-body row col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-8 common-inputs">
    <form role="form" class="left-checkbox-container col-xs-12">
      <div class="custom-checkbox checkbox-title">
        <input type="checkbox" id="common" />
        <label for="common"></label> <span>Common</span>
      </div>
    </form>
    <form role="form" class="left-checkbox-container col-xs-5">
      <div class="custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="post-id" />
        <label for="post-id"></label> <span>ID</span>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="active" name="check" />
        <label for="activation"></label> <span>Active</span>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="info" name="check" />
        <label for="information"></label> <span>info</span>
      </div>
    </form>
    <form role="form" class="left-checkbox-container col-xs-5">
      <div class="custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="onOff" />
        <label for="on-off"></label> <span>on/off</span>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="socialNet" name="check" />
        <label for="social-network"></label> <span>social</span>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="category" name="check" />
        <label for="category"></label> <span>category</span>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button class='btn btn-primary js-ok'>hide/show category</button>

  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class='col-xs-3 post-id'>id</div>
        <div class='col-xs-3 active'>active</div>
        <div class='col-xs-3 info'>info</div>
        <div class='col-xs-3 onOff'>on/off</div>
        <div class='col-xs-3 socialNet'>social</div>
        <div class='col-xs-3 category'>category</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**References**

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

`.attr("checked", false)` is assigning false to the element, and returns it, which evaluates to true ( exists ), you want to compare the attribute, for this you can:

`$('#category').attr("checked") === false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if checkbox checked or not, use this code `$('#category').is(':checked')`, this code `$('#category').attr("checked", false)` set checkbox attr to false, but returns **true**, so your current code just always unchecking **#category** checkbox and hiding **.category** element